# Error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that let's the user choose which operator he wants to use and calculate 10 random equations with that operator. Currently I'm trying to make the code with the "+" operator but it doesn't show the numbers for the user to try and calculate. It only shows the "=" sign and when I input an answer it shows an error code.

This is the code that is causing an error:

```
def operateur(i):
        if i == ("+"):
            count = 0
            total = 0
            while count != 10:    
                numero = str(random.randint(1, 16))
                numero2 = str((random.randint(1, 16)))
                numUtilisateur = float(input("= "))
                print(numero + "+" + numero2 + numUtilisateur)
                reponse = (numero + numero2)
                count+1
                break
            if reponse == (numero + numero2):
                total+1
            else:
                total+0
```

Here is the Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2.py", line 36, in main
    choixOperation = operateur(choixOperation)
  File "c:\Users\vauto\Dropbox\PC\Documents\ALGO CCNB\Travail 2.py", line 12, in operateur
    print(numero + "+" + numero2 + numUtilisateur)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
PS C:\Users\vauto>
```

Comment: Use `,` instead of `+` in your `print` call.

Comment: or cast it to `str`

Comment: what doesn't make sense about the error? it seems pretty clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not append a `float` to a string in Python using `+`.
Only another string. That is what the error is telling you.

If you are using Python 3.6 or higher, you should use "f-strings" to show pretty output with variables, like this:

```
print(f'{numero} + {numero2} = {numUtilisateur}')
```

If you are using an older version of Python, you can format strings like this:

```
print('{} + {} = {}'.format(numero, numero2, numUtilisateur))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the print statement, the `numero` and `numero2` are strings which can be concatenated but your `numUtilisateur` is a float. Convert it to string and then print it. Your print statement would be:
`print(numero + "+" + numero2 + str(numUtilisateur))`